# LockAmountOnline_Active: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF @FlagGenerate = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Lock_Amount_Trx
        (
            Id,Custcode,NoRekDebet,TotalLockAmount,LockStatus,GenerateDate
        )
        SELECT @fileId,tla.cuscode,tla.norekdeb, tla.lockammount,'Active', getdate() FROM ##TempLockActive tla 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT lat.NoRekDebet FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Custcode = tla.cuscode AND lat.TotalLockAmount = tla.lockammount AND lat.GenerateDate =max(lat.GenerateDate))
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT lat.TotalLockAmount FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Custcode = tla.cuscode AND lat.NoRekDebet = tla.norekdeb AND lat.GenerateDate =max(lat.GenerateDate) )
    END
```

I'm trying input from `##TempLockactive` table to `Lock_ammount_trx` if NoRekDebet or TotalLockAmmount or combination of both not have same value from `##TempLockActive` in same row from latest generate date it will do insert the cuscode are the primary key.

I get this error

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Procedure LockAmountOnline_Active, Line 96
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Could someone help me?

Comment: This, `(SELECT lat.NoRekDebet FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Custcode = tla.cuscode AND lat.TotalLockAmount = tla.lockammount AND lat.GenerateDate = max(lat.GenerateDate))`, where should `max(lat.GenerateDate)` come from? In SQL Server you can either get row values or aggregates values in a simple query - never both. For that you would have to consider windows functions.

Comment: Sorry I can't work out your logic but `not exists () or not exists ()` seem unlikely to work? Anyway maybe you want `(select top 1 Value from YourTable order by Date desc)` thats how to get the most recent date from a table.

Comment: I recommend having a read of [Asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and at aminimum adding some sample data and expected results to help us understand your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error message indicated, an aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a sub-query contained.

If the max generate date is exists in the table Lock_Amount_Trx, try to get the max value as a variable before proceed the insert.

My suggestion:

```
IF @FlagGenerate = 0
BEGIN
        DEALLOCATE @maxGenerateDate datetime 
        SET @maxGenerateDate = (SELECT MAX(GenerateDate) FROM Lock_Amount_Trx )

        INSERT INTO Lock_Amount_Trx
        (
            Id,Custcode,NoRekDebet,TotalLockAmount,LockStatus,GenerateDate
        )

        SELECT @fileId,tla.cuscode,tla.norekdeb, tla.lockammount,'Active', getdate() 
        FROM ##TempLockActive tla 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT lat.NoRekDebet FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Custcode = tla.cuscode AND lat.TotalLockAmount = tla.lockammount AND lat.GenerateDate = @maxGenerateDate)
        OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT lat.TotalLockAmount FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat WHERE lat.Custcode = tla.cuscode AND lat.NoRekDebet = tla.norekdeb AND lat.GenerateDate =@maxGenerateDate )
END
```

Comment: @omik919 - you realise that uses the max date from the entire table? Not for a specific `Custcode`. I strongly suspect its giving you incorrect results.

Comment: yes apparently that you're right, i only need max generate date from specific cuscode, NOT all table

Answer (score 0):

Try sub query and join, the logic either NoRekDebet or TotalLockAmoun not exist, right ?

```
IF @FlagGenerate = 0  BEGIN
    SET @maxGenerateDate = (SELECT MAX(GenerateDate) FROM Lock_Amount_Trx )

    INSERT INTO Lock_Amount_Trx
    (
        Id,Custcode,NoRekDebet,TotalLockAmount,LockStatus,GenerateDate
    )

    SELECT @fileId,tla.cuscode,tla.norekdeb, tla.lockammount,'Active', getdate() 
    FROM ##TempLockActive tla 
    -- Left join a sub query with aggragate with max date group by cuscode,norekdeb,lockammount
    -- maybe run the sub query first 
    LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT cuscode,norekdeb,lockammount, MAX(GenerateDate)  maxGenerateDate
     FROM Lock_Amount_Trx
     GROUP BY cuscode,norekdeb,lockammount) sub ON sub.Custcode = tla.cuscode 

    WHERE 
    sub.TotalLockAmount IS NULL OR sub.NoRekDebet IS NULL END
```

Comment: i try to get cuscode that only has max last generate like this                                    
 'SELECT * FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat INNER JOIN 
(SELECT lat2.Custcode,MAX(lat2.GenerateDate) AS maxi FROM Lock_Amount_Trx lat2) bvv
ON lat.Custcode = bvv.Custcode AND lat.GenerateDate = bvv.maxi'                               
 and give me this error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Lock_Amount_Trx.Custcode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: in this part, a group by on a column Custcode is neede,     SELECT lat2.Custcode,MAX(lat2.GenerateDate) AS maxi FROM Lock_Amount_Trx  lat2  group by lat2.Custcode